# How to check if DataGrid control has lost focus

Tags: c#, datagrid, focus, controls, c#-2.0

After datagrid gets focused it shows some buttons on the form. But what is the event that I should use to hide those buttons after datagrid loses it's focus? I should probably mention that this project is done in .Net 2.0.

Comment: what you wrote about buttons on the form is nonsense, nothing to do with datagridview, nothing to do with your question

Answer (score 1):

```
gridview.LostFocus += new EventHandler(gridview_LostFocus);

public void gridview_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Do stuff when focus is lost
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should register on `dataGridView.Leave` event.

Comment: This works, and it's logical to use this. I feel a bit stupid right now :D

Comment: @user2081328 you should feel very stupid, not for not knowing that, but for feeling stupid at not knowing that. It's like feeling stupid because you can't guess something. It's not stupid to not be able to geuss it, but it's unbelievably stupid to feel stupid for not being able to guess.